# Why does this attribute  not change?

Tags: jquery

In the code below the last line is not setting the src attribute. Why?

```
$("div.galerina").each(function(){
    var gal=$(this);
    var bullet=gal.children("img.galerina1");
    var width=12*(gal.children("img").size())+'px';
    gal.children("p").css({width:width})

    gal.children("img").each(function(){
    var img=$(this);
    gal.children("p").append("<img class='bullet' src='images/bullet1.png'></img>");
    $("img.bullet").last().click(function(){
        bullet.animate({opacity:0},300,function(){
            bullet.css({display:'none'});
            bullet=img;
            img.css({display:'block'});
            img.animate({opacity:1},300);
        });

    })
})
gal.children("img.bullet").first().attr("src","images/bullet2.png")
})
```

[LIVE VERSION HERE!!!](http://lookaroundyou.net/galerina)

Comment: We could answer better, if you would setup a demo somewhere like jsfiddle.net. Post some markup also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gal` in not in scope anymore when you try to use it to change the bullet image.

You'll need to either move your last line inside the function passed to `$("div.galerina").each()`, or reinitialize `gal` before you use it:

```
$("div.galerina").each(function() {
    var gal = $(this);
    gal.children("img.bullet").first().attr("src", "images/bullet2.png");
});
```

Comment: @daniel, in that case, you'll need to replace your last line with the code in my answer, else `gal` won't be defined.

Comment: i have edited above code. please take a look and try to see what is wrong. thanks

Comment: @daniel, your updated code suffers from the same problem: `gal` is still out of scope.

Comment: that is impossible. it is inside function where it was declared?? sorry. btw i have tried putting ur code at the end but not working. please look above for link to live version

Comment: @daniel, you're right, sorry, I miscounted the curly braces. The problem is that the bullets are located inside `<p>` elements, and thus are not direct children of the `<div>` elements. Try using `find()` instead of `children()`.

Comment: bravo!! u did it ;) saved my morning. if u ever stop by belgrade, i owe u beer. cheers

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have created gal else where, it's outside of scope. You create a var gal inside of the first each function, but that is local to the each function.

gal is most likely undefined outside. So simply bring the first().attr.... line inside the outer each function.

Comment: Nice Observation... I was wondering what must be wrong in the script.

Comment: Regardless though, you do see that it should be inside of there? Straight after the line in question, put the following alert(gal); Then test, you will probably get null (or undefined?), then move the alert to inside the function and it will alert an array. This is the array that represents gal, from here keeping adding to the alert, so alert(gal.children("img.bullet")); Does this work? If yes move to the next segment, so alert(gal.children("img.bullet").first()); etc until the null or undefined pops up. When it pops up, you know you have your culprit

Comment: it pops up array all the way to atrr("src") and then it gives undefined??

Comment: Ok, we're getting closer. Do the following alert(gal.children('img.bullet').length); and alert(gal.children('img.bullet').first().length);

Comment: thanks Chris. like Frederic said it is because of paragraph nest. many thanks anyways

Comment: Not a problem, probably was going to get to the same place eventually, just not as quick as Frederic. Good luck with the project

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
<img class='bullet' src='images/bullet1.png' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try it using `gal.children` because `gal` is already initiated at `$(this)`. No need to do `$(gal)`

Same goes with `$(img)`

Answer (score 0):

First: Why do you double triple cast a jQuery element? 
var gal=$(this); is a correct jQuery element cast.
From there on gal. and not $(gal).
Then please set semicolon's even if you don't have to. Readabillity reasons.

I think the gal element on your last line is out of scope. 
You defined gal in the scope of $("div.galerina").each(function(){ ... }); On the outside its not longer accessible.